# PHP query with two table

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

In reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305764/connection-between-php-and-access-db/40305818#40305818) topic. 
My problem is that I insert into a table using PHP 5 columns, but one of them is a foreign key to another table. So, I would see the value and not the link directory. 
For example **Orders.Name** contain values "1", "2", "3", "4" etc... they are contained in tables **"Clients"** on columns with **ID** *"1"* the **"Name"** is *"Jack"*, ID "2" the "Name" is "Mark", ID "3" the "Name" is "Frank"... and so on. So, I would to see "Jack", not "1".

Example: 
Database name: **DinamicoWeb** 
Table name: **Orders** 
Fields name: **Id Ord, Ord Date, Name, Price, Total** 
Second Table name: **Clients** 
Fields name: **Id Client, Name, Cell, City, Address**

My actual result:

```
Id Ord   Ord Date    Name    Price    Totale
   1      14/2/99     1       189       345

Id Client   Name       Cell        City       Street
    1       Jack      23445456    Italy      Road nr 2
```

My wish result:

```
Id Ord   Ord Date    Name    Price    Totale
   1      14/2/99    Jack     189       345
```

So, this is my code.
**config.php**

```
<?php
define ('DBNAME',"./DinamicoWeb.mdb"); // Database name
define ('DBTBL',"Orders"); // Table name 1
define ('PKNAME',"Id Ord"); // Primary Key
define ('PKCOL',0); // Position Primary Key
define ('LINKPK',true); // PK link for edit/delete
?>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

$cn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$cnStr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=".
            realpath(DBNAME).";";
$cn->open($cnStr);
$rs = $cn->execute("SELECT [Id Ord] AS [ID], [Ord Date] AS [Date], [Name] AS [Name], [Price] AS [Price], [Total] AS [TOTAL] FROM [Orders]");
$numFields = $rs->Fields->count;

// Print HTML
echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">';
echo '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
echo '<head>';
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
     content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />';
echo '<title>Gestione degli '.DBTBL.'</title>';
echo '<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footable.bootstrap.css">';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footable.bootstrap.min.css">';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footable.core.bootstrap.min.css">';
echo '</head><body>';
echo '<h1>GESTIONE '.DBTBL.'</h1>';
// Elenca records -----
//echo ("<div class='table-responsive'>");
echo ("<table class='datatable table tabella_reponsive ui-responsive' summary='Prova dati con MS Access'>");
echo("<caption>Tabella ".DBTBL."</caption>\n");
echo("<thead><tr>\n");
for ($i=0;$i<$numFields;$i++){
    echo("<th scope='col'>");
    echo $rs->Fields($i)->name;
    echo("</th>\n");
}
echo("</tr></thead>\n");
echo("<tbody>");

$alt = false;
while (!$rs->EOF)
{
    echo("<tr>");
    for ($i=0;$i<$numFields;$i++){
      $altClass = $alt ? " class='alt'" : "";
      if (LINKPK && $i==PKCOL){
        echo "<td".$altClass."><a href='?id=".$rs->Fields($i)->value
              ."'>".$rs->Fields($i)->value."</a></td>\n";
      }
      else{
        echo "<td".$altClass.">".$rs->Fields($i)->value."</td>\n";
      }
    }
    echo("</tr>\n");    
    $rs->MoveNext();
    $alt = !$alt;
}
echo("</tbody>");
echo("</table>\n");
echo("</div>");
echo '<script src="js/footable.js"></script>';
echo '<script src="js/footable.min.js"></script>';
}
echo '</body></html>';
$rs->Close();
$cn->Close();
?>
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** 
I have relationship between Client and Order table.

This is my query on Access. (Different name and different request)

```
SELECT DISTINCT Ordini.[Id Ord], Ordini.[Tipo Ord] AS Tipo, Ordini.[N Ord] AS Numero, Ordini.[Data Ord] AS Data, Ordini.Anno, Anagrafica.CodAnag AS Codice, Ordini.[Ragione sociale], IIf([stato]=0,"inserito",IIf([stato]=1,"stampato","Bloccato")) AS [Stato ord], Ordini.[Data consegna] AS Consegna, Ordini.ValidoFinoAl AS Validità, [tabella pagamenti].Descrizione AS Pagamento, Ordini.Rif1 AS [Ns Riferimenti], Ordini.Rif2 AS [Vs Riferimenti], IIf(Not IsNull([idsped]),[anagrafica spedizioni].[Ragione Sociale] & " " & [anagrafica spedizioni].Indirizzo & " " & [anagrafica spedizioni].Località,IIf(Not IsNull(anagrafica_1.[id anag]),anagrafica_1.[Ragione Sociale] & " " & anagrafica_1.Indirizzo & " " & anagrafica_1.Località)) AS Destinazione, Ordini.TotImp, Ordini.TotNI, Ordini.Cambio, Temp_Ordini_Interroga.ApertoEuro, Temp_Ordini_Interroga.TotaleEuro, Ordini.Sospeso
FROM ((((Ordini INNER JOIN Anagrafica ON Ordini.[Id anag] = Anagrafica.[Id anag]) INNER JOIN [tabella pagamenti] ON Ordini.[Id pagamento] = [tabella pagamenti].[Id pagamento]) LEFT JOIN [anagrafica spedizioni] ON (Ordini.DestSped = [anagrafica spedizioni].CodSped) AND (Ordini.Dest = [anagrafica spedizioni].[Id anag])) LEFT JOIN Anagrafica AS Anagrafica_1 ON Ordini.Dest = Anagrafica_1.[Id anag]) INNER JOIN Temp_Ordini_Interroga ON Ordini.[Id Ord] = Temp_Ordini_Interroga.IdOrd
ORDER BY Ordini.Anno DESC , Ordini.[Data Ord] DESC , Ordini.[N Ord] DESC;
```

Comment: You have some relationship between client and order table

Comment: What you can do is use JOIN on your query and the relationship would be Orders.[Name] = Clients.[Id Ord]

Comment: @jaidutt yes, i have.

Comment: @bagiak you can check my answer

Comment: The correct sintax is `Orders.[Name]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your question, but i think you should try to change your query for example:

```
SELECT [Id Ord] AS [ID], [Ord Date] AS [Date], [Clients.name] AS [Name], [Price] AS [Price], [Total] AS [TOTAL] FROM [Orders] LEFT JOIN [Clients] ON [Clients.id]=[Orders.name]
```

Comment: I try this solution, but doesn't work. Message: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers<br/><b>Description:</b> [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access] Parentesi non valide nel nome '[Clients.Id]'.`

Comment: Maybe something like this: `code`Clients.[Id Client] = Orders.[name]`code`

Comment: Maybe something like this: `Clients.[Id Client] = Orders.[name]`

Comment: And in the selected field `Clients.[name] AS [name]`

Comment: I change the code, now there aren't error on editor and final page. But it doesn't working, I don't know the cause.

Comment: is the variable `$numFields` > 0, echo the var to see the value if there is no value maybe the call of adodb is not correct. Then look at this topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245140/how-to-get-field-names-using-php-adodb)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    [Orders.Id Ord] AS [ID], [Orders.Ord Date] AS [Date], 
    [Clients.Name] AS [Name], [Orders.Price] AS [Price], 
    [Orders.Total] AS [TOTAL] 
FROM 
    [Orders] 
JOIN
    Clients ON Orders.name = clients.client id;
```

**NOTE**: remove spaces in column's name.

Comment: I try this solution, but doesn't work. Message: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers<br/><b>Description:</b> [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access] Parentesi non valide nel nome '[Clients.Id]'.`

Comment: Not work. The right sintax is `Orders.[Name]` like suggest @th3fr33man , but if i change both code don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do not repeat same name with as in sql. Also do not keep space when assign name for column. Use underscore (_) for word separation.

```
SELECT [Id Ord] AS [ID], [Ord Date] AS [Date], [Name] , [Price], [Total] 
FROM [Orders],[Clients]
WHERE [Orders.Name]=[Clients.Id];
```

Comment: I try this solution, but doesn't work. Message: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers<br/><b>Description:</b> [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access] Parentesi non valide nel nome '[Clients.Id]'.`

Comment: You can't use this way '[Clients.Id]'. Use this as ``Clients.Id``

Comment: I already try. Message: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers<br/><b>Description:</b> [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access] Syntax error (missing operator) in query 'Clients.Id=Orders.Name'`

Comment: What is this 'Clients.Id=Orders.Id'?

Comment: I did a mistake when copied the error, now i edited the last comment, sorry. I can't use `Clients.'Id Client';`

Comment: ah . You can add (') this as above. for that use this as Clients.Id=Orders.Name or [Clients.Id]=[Orders.Name]. unless replace bracket with (`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127305/discussion-between-chandana-kumara-and-m-bagiak).

Answer (score 0):

you have to use join in your sql request.

example :

```
Select orders.idOrd, orders.ordDate, client.name, orders.price, orders.totale 
From orders
join client on client.idClient = orders.Name
```

you can also use alias for table as :

```
Select o.idOrd, o.ordDate, c.name, o.price, o. totale
From orders o
join client c on c.idClient = o.Name
```

This request will select the corresponding name from the client table in c.name column.

You should rename the "name" column in the orders table as "ClientId" to be 
coherent.

Comment: This doesn't work if I write "Orders.Id ord" (with space). How can I rename all columns on PHP (not on DB Access)?